# WPF C# Filtering ListView's items with many criteria

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

[image: An Online-Shopping sites Filter example taken from amazon.com]

If you guys visit amazon.com and search for "Movies", you will see the above filters.

In my app i have a `ListView` with some `MovieItem`s in it. A few days ago, 
I've successfully filtered the `ListView` with a Search Box. Then yesterday, i visited amazon.com and looked at the filters panel above. I wonder if i could apply it in my app too. So created a simple Filter Panel for my `ListView`'s items:

[image: My Filter Panel]

Unfortunately, since i am new to wpf and c# language, i have no idea to do that :(

So pls can someone tell me what should i do?

FYI, `MovieItem` class:

```
    public class MovieItem
    {
    public string aRomajiTitle { get; set; }
    public string bEnglishTitle { get; set; }
    public string cType { get; set; }
    public string dScore { get; set; }
    public string eEpisodes { get; set; }
    public string fJapaneseTitle { get; set; }
    public string gGenres { get; set; }
    public string hSynopsis { get; set; }
    public string iDuration { get; set; }
    public string jStatus { get; set; }
    public string kMALID { get; set; }
    public string lMyStatus { get; set; }
    public string mDownloaded { get; set; }
    public string nWatched { get; set; }
    public string oMyScore { get; set; }
    public string pKeywords { get; set; }
    public string qPicURL { get; set; }
    public string rLocalPic { get; set; }
    public string sEpsAcc { get; set; }
    public string tRewatched { get; set; }
    public string uNotes { get; set; }
    public string zImage_url_med { get; set; }
    public string zImage_url_sml { get; set; }
    public string zStart_date { get; set; }
    public string zEnd_date { get; set; }
    public string zHashtag { get; set; }
    public string zSource { get; set; }
    public string zSynonyms { get; set; }
    public string zImageBanner { get; set; }
    public string zYoutube_ID { get; set; }
    public bool zAdult { get; set; }
    public int? zPopularity { get; set; }
    public string zRelation_type { get; set; }
    public string zRole { get; set; }
    public bool favourite { get; set; }
    public int? season { get; set; }
    public List<Subclass_SmallReviewModel> reviews { get; set; }
    public List<CharacterWithActor_Model> characters { get; set; }
    public List<Staff_Model_Small> staff { get; set; }
    public List<OP_SMALL_Model> OPS { get; set; }
    public List<ED_SMALL_Model> EDS { get; set; }
    public List<Subclass_Studio_Model> studio { get; set; }
    public List<Subclass_Ext_Links> external_links { get; set; }
    public Subclass_Airing zAiring { get; set; }

}
```

ListView XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="DM_AllMovies_List" Panel.ZIndex="0" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="671" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="902" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Foreground="Black" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" BorderBrush="#FFC54B4B" BorderThickness="3" Background="White" MouseDown="DM_AllMovie_List_MouseDown" Margin="0,0,0,-3">
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <mwc:VirtualizingWrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        </ListView>
```

The `ListView`'s  `ItemsSource` is `List` of `MovieItem`s.

```
        public void LoadMyList()
    {
        DM_AllMovies_List.ItemsSource = null;
        List<MovieItem> MovieDataSource_AllMovies = new List<MovieListViewItem_V2>();

        string json = File.ReadAllText(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Database\DMTitles.col");

        List<MovieItem> js = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MovieListViewItem_V2>>(json);

        DM_AllMoview_List.ItemsSource = js;
    }
```

Tell me if you need to see the the `ListView`'s `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: Yes you can do that, post your code and the list that you are binding

Comment: @Sajeetharan I added the code. Thx for fast reply :)

Comment: you can use linq query and apply the fiter whenever they select the check box

Comment: @Sajeetharan Oh i see, this LINQ Query is new to me :D I checked it on MSDN and it looks promising, you comeback later, i want to learn it now a bit. Once again, Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @Sajeetharan Now i understand the basic of linq query, but still i cant implement what you said, can u give me an example? I'm a type of person who learn faster with an example :D

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/linq-to-object-part-sharp2-filtering-and-sorting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi as I can understand you need to filter the whole items collection using some filter predicate. If so, I can suggest you to use the CollectionView as a SourceItems for your collection.In addition please notice that all collections you binded them from XAML have to be of type ObservableCollection else you get memory leaks in your application. Here I put several articles to help you to understand how to work with the CollectionView:

1. The [filter an observable collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615891/filter-an-observable-collection) .
2. [How to Navigate, Group, Sort and Filter Data in WPF](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dataviews.html).

Regards,

Comment: Firstly, thx for the answer :D You're right! I need to filter my MovieItems inside the listview with some predicate. I will try your suggestion