# Update an ObservableCollection that is the result of another ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

Excuse me but I didn't know how to formulate the question :

I have two ObservableCollection

ObservableCollection MyMainList
is the ObservableCollection where are stored all of my objects.

```
ObservableCollection<T> MyFilteredList = new ObservableCollection(MyMainList.Where(x=>Condition))
```

is the ObservableCollection filtered according some parameters.

At one moment, I need to add or remove objects from MyMainList, but then MyFilteredList is not updated automatically.

I need always to do :

```
MyMainList.Add(newObject);
MyFilteredList.Add(newObject);
```

Is there a way to do all of that in just one line, so when I modify MyMainList, MyFilteredList will be automatically updated?

Edit : To answer to Adriano Repetti, when I open my window, I load all of objects (so I don't need to reload my DB everytime I change filters).
I have three different filters :
 - 1 combobox "Affaire" (list of the contracts)
 - 1 combobox "Phase" (list of the subcontracts)
 - 1 TextBox "Filter" ( if I want to see only objects whose name contains that text).

When I change selection of 1st ComboBox, I update the list of subcontracts, and update the filtered list of assemblies.

```
private Affaire selectedAffaire;
public Affaire SelectedAffaire
{
   get { return selectedAffaire; }
   set
   {
      selectedAffaire = value;
      this.NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedAffaire");
      if (value != null)
      {
         GetListPhaseInContract(); //I update the list of subcontracts in 2nd Combobox
      }
      UpdateListAssemblages(); // I update MyFilteredList
   }
}
```

When I change selection of 2nd ComboBox (subcontract), I update the list of MyFilteredList

```
private Phase selectedPhase;
public Phase SelectedPhase
{
   get { return selectedPhase; }
   set
   {
       selectedPhase = value;
       this.NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedPhase");
       UpdateListAssemblages();
   }
}
```

Then when I change my TextBox value, I also update the list

```
private string texteFiltre;
public string TexteFiltre
{
   get { return texteFiltre; }
   set
   {
      texteFiltre = value;
      this.NotifyPropertyChanged("TexteFiltre");
      UpdateListAssemblages();
   }
}
```

If I understood, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615891/filter-an-observable-collection) is what I need to look for? I don't know yet what are ICollectionView, but I guess I need to look in that way?Will I gain some execution time using ICollectionView? as I see I need anyway to Refresh it?

Comment: I don't know what your design is but in this case I'd avoid to have a **copy** of your data, as you can see it's hard to keep them in sync. What I'd use is a **view** of the observable collection (which might be smart enough to fire the appropriate events or a dumb view which always fires `Reset`).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yes in fact I think I am doing something wrong (I am new with MVVM concept). Could you please explain me how I can define these filtered views? Because in that case it is pretty simple, but sometimes I have a view that is a filter of a collectionview, and conditions are on selected elements of a second view. I will now edit my post to put some more concrete code(and I am aware I am doing something wrong).

Comment: You can have multiple views based on one collection and filters can be as complicated as you like so long as they return a bool for any given record.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26673.wpf-collectionview-tips.aspx

Comment: Take a look at [DynamicData](https://dynamic-data.org/), it is far more powerfull than Views of observable collections

Comment: Very similar question asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256793/mvvm-sync-collections). That case involves synching two different types of collections, your scenario is more simple.

Comment: Ok thanks all for your answers, I definitely will look further in documentations, until now I didn't use them(cause I didn't manage to use them), but I see this will be very helpful.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti thanks, I made a tutorial (www.blackwasp.co.uk) and finally understood all about 'ICollectionView'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't give us the detial of the data struct, I just assume that `PhaseInContract` is included in `MainList`. So, just simply create two views for your `MainList`, then binding them to UI. All views will synchronize with source automatically.

```
Public ICollectionView MainListView;
Public ICollectionView PhaseInContractView;
Public ObservableCollection<YourDataClass> MainList;

public YourViewModel()
{
    MainList = new ObservableCollection<YourDataClass>();

    // Load datas form db and fill MainList

    MainListView = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = MainList }.View;
    MainListView.Filter = (x) =>
    {
        // your MainListView filtering logic.
    };

    PhaseInContractView = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = MainList }.View;
    PhaseInContractView.Filter = (x) =>
    {
        // your PhaseInContractView filtering logic
    };

private Affaire selectedAffaire;
public Affaire SelectedAffaire
{
    get { return selectedAffaire; }
    set
    {
        selectedAffaire = value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedAffaire");
        if (value != null)
        {
           PhaseInContractView.Refresh();
        }
        MainListView.Refresh();
    }
}

// And other properties.
...
```

Comment: in fact I made the tutorial on ICollectionView (www.blackwasp.co.uk), and that helped solving my problem, need to update all of my project with these views, very useful. Thanks